# Pandas: getting a list inside a dataframe as row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, series

I have a list like this:

`l1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

This list is supposed to be a row of a dataframe, which I create empty like this:

`df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'], 
                      index=['l1','l2','l3','l4'])`

Now I want the values of `l1` to appear in the first row of the dataframe. How can I do this?

My attempt:
`df.loc['l1'] = pd.Series(l1)`

but this returns an empty dataframe:

```
     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
l1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
l2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
l3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
l4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: `df.loc['l1'] = pd.Series(l1)` fails because the default index label doesn't match your existing columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply `list`:

```
df.loc['l1'] = l1
print (df)                      
      A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
l1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
l2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
l3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
l4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or add parameter `index` with values of `df.column`, because `index` of `Series` has to be same as `columns` of `DataFrame` for alignment:

```
df.loc['l1'] = pd.Series(l1, index = df.columns)
print (df)                      
      A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H
l1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
l2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
l3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
l4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```